# Grep for a string that ends with specific character

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Is there a way to use extended regular expressions to find a specific pattern that ends with a string.

I mean, I want to match first 3 lines but not the last:

```
file_number_one.pdf # comment
file_number_two.pdf # not interesting
testfile_number____three.pdf # some other stuff
myfilezipped.pdf.zip some comments and explanations
```

I know that in grep, metacharacter $ matches the end of a line but I'm not interested in matching a line end but string end. Groups in grep are very odd, I don't understand them well yet.

I tried with group matching, actually I have a similar REGEX but it does not work with grep -E

```
(\w+).pdf$
```

Is there a way to do string ending match in grep/egrep?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your example works with matching the space after the string also:

```
grep -E '\.pdf ' input.txt
```

What you call "string" is similar to what grep calls "word". A Word is a run of alphanumeric characters. The nice thing with words is that you can match a word end with the special `\>`, which matches a word end with a march of zero characters length. That also matches at the end of line. But the word characters can not be changed, and do not contain punctuation, so we can not use it.

If you need to match at the end of line too, where there is no space after the word, use:

```
grep -E '\.pdf |\.pdf$' input.txt
```

To include cases where the character after the file name is not a space character '', but other whitespace, like a tab, `\t`, or the name is directly followed by a comment, starting with `#`, use:

```
grep -E '\.pdf[[:space:]#]|\.pdf$' input.txt
```

I will illustrate the matching of word boundarys too, because that would be the perfect solution, except that we can not use it here because we can not change the set of characters that are seen as parts of a word.

The input contains `foo` as separate word, and as part of longer words, where the `foo` is not at the end of the word, and therefore not at a word boundary:

```
$ printf 'foo bar\nfoo.bar\nfoobar\nfoo_bar\nfoo\n'
foo bar
foo.bar
foobar
foo_bar
foo
```

Now, to match the boundaries of words, we can use `\<` for the beginning, and `\>` to match the end:

```
$ printf 'foo bar\nfoo.bar\nfoobar\nfoo_bar\nfoo\n' | grep 'foo\>'
foo bar
foo.bar
foo
```

Note how `_` is matched as a word char - but otherwise, wordchars are only the alphanumerics, `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.
Also note how `foo` an the end of line is matched - in the line containing only `foo`. We do not need a special case for the end of line.

Comment: I would say this is very similar to the solution I'm searching for. Can you give me an example with matching end of the word with `\>`?

Comment: I have updated the answer with showing the word boundary matching too.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `.` in your regex. This regex will match anything that ends in .pdf (and only things that end in .pdf):

```
grep '.*\.pdf$' filename
```

Comment: The OP wants to match lines ending in .pdf

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\>` operator

```
grep 'word\>' fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Positive lookaheads are the most suited for this kinda stuff. Have a try :

```
grep -P "(^\w+\.pdf)(?=\s)" file
```

I assume filenames will always be on the start of the line.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. It might be working regex in other environment but it's not suited for **grep** I think. It just does not match anything.